# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on FileOutputStream when receiving data from Server

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, randomaccessfile

I want to develop an android application that receive files from server.

The server send first a packet with **(FileOriginalName and FileLength)**, then it's start to send datas packet  ( one by one / bloc by bloc) , each packet contains **(8Kb file datas and blocIndex)**.

when i receive the first packet, i create a file with given Length :

```
      RandomAccessFile f = null;
        try {
            f = new RandomAccessFile(originalFileName, "rw");
            f.setLength(length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

then i call the following code each time i recive a datas packets from server :

```
              FileOutputStream _fOS = new FileOutputStream(fileOriginalPath);
            _fOS.write(blockData, blockIndex << 13, blockData.length);
            _fOS.close();
```

i get the following error on _fOS.write :

**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5077; regionStart=8192; regionLength=5077**

Comment: It can write only data receiving from the first packet, means can write first datas packet only

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution,

for the first packet, i only save the **originalFileName**,

for the datas packets,

```
 for each received packet i call the following method

            RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(originalFileName, "rw");
            f.seek(blockIndex << 13);
            f.write(blockData);
            f.close();
```

hope that will help, thank you